# IOS, is it posible to call control center in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Like my question, I want to launch control center to turn on wifi? 
Is it posible to call control center in xcode?
[some image of control center](https://www.google.com.vn/search?es_sm=119&biw=1683&bih=913&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=control%20center%20ios&btnG=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to launch control center from the application. May be it is possible in upcoming version.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. And it won't be in the foreseeable future.